# Clarification on Bing Maps API locationCode field

Tags: bing-maps

I'm working on learning the Bing Maps API for my current project at work.  In various locations in route and traffic data output, there is a field called locationCode (or locationCodes).  The documentation provides no clarification on what this field is, except to state: "A subscription is typically required to be able to interpret these codes for a geographical area or country."

Nothing I've been able to find yet defines this further or clarifies what data that code can be translated into by these subscription services.  So, what are some of the services available to translate this code and what data can be obtained via these services?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you see this documented?

Comment: The links Nicolas added below point in the right area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those information are related to traffic for specific roads, see the details for the API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441726.aspx

Also the description of each field included in the result:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441730.aspx

You are referring to the locationCode. Those are related to the Traffic Message Channel information where the included information are the event id, the location code, expected incident duration, affected extent and other details.

Those TMC are managed in different ways depending on the country you are interested in and specialised mapping data provider can give you access to those kind of information and that's what the subscription is about. It is also related to the way you can use the TMC depending on the concerned area to get or give information from there.

For more information about TMC: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_message_channel

Comment: The question eventually became moot, but the information you've provided and linked to provides some good clarification.